# "Invalid operand for instruction" error in arm64 architecture for ios

Tags: ios, assembly, arm64

I am getting compilation error when trying to run the below inline assembly instruction in arm64 architecture.Works fine with 32-bit architecture.

Store instruction stores the stack pointer(sp) to variable stack_ptr.

```
unsigned long stack_ptr = 0;

__asm__ __volatile__("str sp, %[stack_ptr]"
                     :[stack_ptr]"=m" (stack_ptr) //output operand list
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

In 64 bit code, you can't use `SP` as operand in `STR` instruction. Quoting the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1424433163841.html):

> You can only use SP as an operand in the following instructions:
>
> - As the base register for loads and stores. In this case it must be quadword-aligned before adding any offset, or a stack alignment
>     exception occurs.
> - As a source or destination for arithmetic instructions, but it cannot be used as the destination in instructions that set the
>     condition flags.
> - In logical instructions, for example in order to align it.

You should copy it into a general purpose register first, then store it into memory.

Unless you need a truly precise value, you could just use plain C and take the address of the local variable itself to get an estimate of the stack pointer:

```
unsigned long stack_ptr = (unsigned long)&stack_ptr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I moved value of SP to a temp register. Then it worked.